# In the terminal How are block letters created, and is there any easy way to generate them yourself?

Tags: shell, unix, command-line, terminal

Like this from oh-my-zsh:

[image: oh my zsh]

Is there an easy way to replicate this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just found this ... [FIGlet](http://www.figlet.org/).

Answer (score 0):

See also [`Zend_Text_Figlet`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.text.figlet.html)

```
$figlet = new Zend_Text_Figlet();
echo $figlet->render('Zend');
```